# Calling from the same class, why is one treated as bound method while the other plain function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, methods, sqlalchemy

I have the following code snippet in Python 3:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Unicode, UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method
import arrow


datetimeString_format = {
    "UTC": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00",
    "local_with_timezoneMarker": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z",
    "local_without_timezoneMarker": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}

dateString_format = "%Y-%m-%d"




class My_TimePoint_Mixin:
    # define output formats:
    datetimeString_inUTC_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00"
    datetimeString_naive_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    # instrumented fields:
    _TimePoint_in_database = Column('timepoint', String, nullable=False)
    _TimePoint_in_database_suffix = Column(
    'timepoint_suffix', String, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def timepoint(self):
        twoPossibleType_handlers = [
            self._report_ACCRT_DATE,
            self._report_ACCRT_DATETIME
        ]
        for handler in twoPossibleType_handlers:
            print("handler: ", handler)
            try:
                return handler(self)
            except (AssertionError, ValueError) as e:
                logging.warning("Try next handler!")

    @timepoint.setter
    def timepoint(self, datetimepointOBJ):
        handlers_lookup = {
            datetime.datetime: self._set_ACCRT_DATETIME,
            datetime.date: self._set_ACCRT_DATE
        }
        this_time = type(datetimepointOBJ)
        this_handler = handlers_lookup[this_time]
        print("handler: ", this_handler)
        this_handler(datetimepointOBJ)

    def _report_ACCRT_DATE(self):
        """Accurate Date"""
        assert self._TimePoint_in_database_suffix == "ACCRT_DATE"
        date_string = self._TimePoint_in_database
        dateString_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
        # return a datetime.date
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, dateString_format).date()

    def _report_ACCRT_DATETIME(self):
        """Accurate DateTime"""
        assert self._TimePoint_in_database_suffix in pytz.all_timezones_set
        datetimeString_inUTC = self._TimePoint_in_database
        utc_naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        datetimeString_inUTC, self.datetimeString_inUTC_format)
        utc_timepoint = arrow.get(utc_naive, "utc")
        # localize
        local_timepoint = utc_timepoint.to(self._TimePoint_in_database_suffix)
        # return a datetime.datetime
        return local_timepoint.datetime

    def _set_ACCRT_DATETIME(self, datetimeOBJ_aware):
        assert isinstance(datetimeOBJ_aware, datetime.datetime), "Must be a valid datetime.datetime!"
        assert datetimeOBJ_aware.tzinfo is not None, "Must contain tzinfo!"
        utctime_aware_arrow = arrow.get(datetimeOBJ_aware).to('utc')
        utctime_aware_datetime = utctime_aware_arrow.datetime
        store_datetime_string = utctime_aware_datetime.strftime(
        self.datetimeString_inUTC_format)
        self._TimePoint_in_database = store_datetime_string

    def _set_ACCRT_DATE(self, dateOBJ):
        store_date_string = dateOBJ.isoformat()
        self._TimePoint_in_database = store_date_string
```

For some reason, the getter's handler is treated as a plain function rather than a method, hence the need to explicitly provide 'self' as its argument.

Is it because of the looping? Or because of the `try...except` structure? Why is this the case that within the same class, handlers are treated differently? (The setter's handlers are treated as bound method as expected).

Comment: See, that was important, because I now see you have a `hybrid_property`. This can be executed both on an instance (with bound methods) and on the *class* (where the methods will be unbound, there is nothing to bind *to*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not a regular `property` here, you have a [SQLAlchemy `@hybrid_property` object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html). Quoting the documentation there:

> “hybrid” means the attribute has distinct behaviors defined at the class level and at the instance level.

and

> When dealing with the `Interval` class itself, the `hybrid_property` descriptor evaluates the function body given the `Interval` class as the argument, which when evaluated with SQLAlchemy expression mechanics returns a new SQL expression:
>
> ```
> >>> print Interval.length
> interval."end" - interval.start
> ```

So the property is used in a *dual capacity*, both on instances, and on the class.

In the case of the property being used on the class itself, `self` is bound to (a subclass of) `My_TimePoint_Mixin` and the methods are not bound. There is nothing to bind *to* in that case as there is no instance.

You'll have to take this into account when coding a `hybrid_property` getter (the setter only applies to the *on an instance* case). Your assertions at the start of `_report_ACCRT_DATE` and `_report_ACCRT_DATETIME` won't hold, for example.

You can distinguish between the *instance* case and the *expression* (on the class) case, by declaring a separate getter for the latter with the `hybrid_property.expression` decorator:

```
@hybrid_property
def timepoint(self):
    twoPossibleType_handlers = [
        self._report_ACCRT_DATE,
        self._report_ACCRT_DATETIME
    ]
    for handler in twoPossibleType_handlers:
        print("handler: ", handler)
        try:
            return handler(self)
        except (AssertionError, ValueError) as e:
            logging.warning("Try next handler!")

@timepoint.expression
def timepoint(cls):
    # return a SQLAlchemy expression for this virtual column
```

SQLAlchemy will then use the `@timepoint.expression` class method for the `My_TimePoint_Mixin.timepoint` use, and use the original getter only on `My_TimePoint_Mixin().timepoint` instance access. See the [*Defining Expression Behavior Distinct from Attribute Behavior* section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior).

Comment: There seems no SQL expression equivalent to generic function dispatching construct. The closest thing in a SQL expression seems to be the CASE from the func. Anyone can provide a better solution than "CASE"?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu: no, I'd say you are stuck with `CASE` here.